# JQL search query to select all tasks in an epic, that are not 'linked' to a story

Tags: jira, jql

Im currently trying to get a list of all tasks/spikes/bugs in an epic that do not have a linked issue.

Something like : `parent=CAL-274 and linkedIssue is EMPTY`

But cant get this to work.

Context. We have an epic that has user stories (created by PO) and linked to that Story are one or many Tasks/spikes etc that are created by all who need to work towards implementing the user story. We dont want to use subtasks as it messes up the sprint at the story level end of the sprint. I would love to see all 'tasks' that do not link with a user story so that we can review them and link them to user stories. Has anyone found an easy way to do this in JQL?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your linked issues ***block*** a Story, then you can ***get all issues in an Epic, that are not linked to a story*** via this JQL:

```
parent = PROJ-1 AND issueLinkType is EMPTY
```